# How do I link to a certain section of the page (that works in Safari)

Tags: html, css

I have a testimonials page and I have a sample testimonial on the homepage with an option to "Read More." When the user clicks read more, I want it to go to the testimonials page directly down to the section where that particular testimonial is.

So what I did is wrap that particular testimonial in a div and give it an ID. Then on the link on the homepage, I added #ID to the end of the URL. It works perfectly in Mozilla and Chrome. It goes directly to that section. However when I try it on Safari, the #ID part disappears from the browser when I click the link and it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: <a href="http://mywebsite.com/thepageIwanttolinkto#theIDofthediv">Read More</a>

Answer (score 0):

Does it work without breaking Chrome and Mozilla if you put an anchor such as

```
<a name="yourAnchor"></a>
```

in the testimonial div? If so, perhaps the version of Safari you're testing with doesn't     fully support HTML5.

Comment: I just downloaded the latest version of Safari. I tried <a name="anchor"> and it doesn't work :(